# Access state within nested utility functions

Tags: python, pandas, software-design

I've created a `metadata` object in my `transformations.py`. I want to access it in utility functions such as `utils/some_fn` . What is the best way to do so?

```py
# metadata.py
class Metadata:
    
    def __init__(self, year, sheet_name) -> None:
        self.year = year
        self.sheet_name = sheet_name
        

def create_metadata(sheet_name):
    metadata = Metadata(year=2023, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    return metadata

# main.py

import pandas as pd

sheet_names_by_dfs = pd.read_excel('a workbook.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for sheet_name, df in sheet_names_by_dfs:
    transformations(sheet_name, df)

# transformations.py
from utils import some_fn

def transformations(sheet_name, df):
    metadata = create_metadata(sheet_name)
    ...
    some_fn()

# utils.py

def some_fn():
    # How can I go about accessing metadata?
    pass
```

Comment: You could put the metadata in a global variable

Comment: Or pass it as an argument to `some_fn`

Comment: @Barmar 

I actually do want to make it a global variable, because my ideal way of using `metadata` would be importing it within the `utils` module. The problem is that `create_metadata` depends on `sheet_name` which is passed to `transformations` so I can't make it a global variable.

 I also don't want to have to pass `metadata` as an argument to every single util function I end up using.

Comment: So you have different metadata for each sheet name? You can put them in a dictionary. Maybe the `Metadata` class should handle this for you, so you can look up the metadata for a given sheet name.

Comment: @Barmar So it isn't really that the metadata is different for each sheet name. It's that the metadata should be recreated for each sheet, and each sheet should include the different sheet name for that specific sheet. So with every call to `transformations` in the `main.py` loop, I want to recreate a new `metadata` object that contains the current sheet name. And I want to be able to access this `metadata` object in my other utils via an import.

Comment: Sounds like you need a class for sheets, and it should include its metadata.

Comment: @Barmar The problem still persists that I don't have a way to access the class for sheets in my utils module via import, to access its metadata, since each sheet will be instantiated within `transformations` I assume.

Comment: You can't access local variables from a function, since they go away when the function ends. It has to save the information somewhere -- a global variable, a return value, a class property, etc.

Comment: `transformations()` has to put the metadata somewhere that `some_fn()` can access it.

Comment: @Barmar Yepp completely agree, I'm just completely lost on where specifically `transformations` should put metadata